# Yahoo Answers API: Why is there is a maximum limit to the 'start' parameter?

Tags: yahoo-api

According to this [Yahoo Answer's API](http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/questionSearch.html), the 'start' parameter, which determines how far back in the Yahoo Answers database your query can reach, is limited to 1000.  This means, at maximum, you can get a total of 1050 answers of Yahoo's database.

Does anybody know why this limitation exists and if there is a way around it?

Comment: Removing the python tag since this doesn't appear to have anything at all to do with Python.

Comment: Oops, sorry-- I just program in Python, so I was hoping the response would take the form of Python code.

Comment: Most "search" APIs like this (especially from Yahoo and Google) will have a limited range of results you can get for a given query. The reasons: 1) presumably the most useful results will appear in the first few pages of results and 2) prevent other sites or apps from doing a full extraction of the data.